# Parse push notification

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use Push Notification for my libgdx Android app with Parse SDK 1.5.1. That's why I checked the documentation and I add it into my AndroidManifest.xml. But I have two builds (release and debug), that's why I add `${applicationId}` in my main-AndroidManifest.xml file.

The debug build works like I wanted it, but the release build logcat shows

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.parse.PushRouter$8$1.run(PushRouter.java:235)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.parse.ParseInstallation.updateVersionInfo(ParseInstallation.java:297)
        at com.parse.ParseInstallation.updateBeforeSave(ParseInstallation.java:213)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.saveEventually(ParseObject.java:1551)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.saveEventually(ParseObject.java:1521)
        at com.parse.PushRouter.subscribe(PushRouter.java:626)
        at com.parse.PushRouter$1.then(PushRouter.java:72)
        at com.parse.PushRouter$1.then(PushRouter.java:69)
        at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
        at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
        at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
        at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
        at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
        at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:381)
        at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:373)
        at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

What could be my failure?

My code in the Application class is:

```
Parse.initialize(this, ParseEndpoint.getAppId(), ParseEndpoint.getClientKey());
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, AndroidLauncher.class);
```

If I remove the second line, everything worked, but no push will be available, but that's logical.

Comment: Instead of giving -1 would it be better to say, why you give -1 or ask for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. My APK didn't have a versionName defined. I will open an bug report for Parse, because the stack trace was no really help. Maybe they could do it better.